# Laravel @foreach - invalid argument supplied

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to Laravel and PHP, just trying to list all users in my view file like this:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <li>{{ link_to("/users/{$user->username}", $user->username) }}</li>
@endforeach
```

But getting an error which says 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

In my controller, I have the following function:

```
public function users() {
    $user = User::all();
    return View::make('users.index', ['users' => '$users']);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$users` is not defined in your controller, but `$user` is. You are trying to `@foreach` over a variable that literally equals the string `'$users'`.  Change:

```
$user = User::all();
```

to:

```
$users = User::all();
```

And remove the single quotes around `$users`:

```
return View::make('users.index', ['users' => $users]);
```

Comment: np, glad I could help

Comment: Jeff this is really helpful

Answer (score 5):

The answer above is correct, but since others may have the same error (which basically means that the variable you have supplied to foreach is not an array) in a different context, let me give this as another cause:

- When you have an eloquent relationship (probably a hasMany) which has the same name as a fieldin that eloquent model, and you want to loop through the items in the relationship using a foreach. You will think you are looping through the relationship yet Laravel is treating the field as having a higher precedence than the relationship. Solution is to rename your relationship (or field, whatever the case).

Comment: What a nice answer. Just overcame my problem.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```php
foreach ($allresults as $key => $vl) {
    foreach ($vl as $vll) {
        print_r($vll->customerid);
    }
}
```

Shows error *"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"*,
but after add line `break`, it working:

```php
foreach ($allresults as $key => $vl) {
    foreach ($vl as $vll) {
        print_r($vll->customerid);
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include  an explanation of how this works and why it is the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].